# Trying to run a Classification Tree on some data but pulling this error

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a Classification Tree on data about Visa applications (includes categories such as workplace, average pay, etc.) but I'm pulling the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-33e98dd52d68> in <module>
      3 from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
      4 clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
----> 5 y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf, x, y, cv=10)
      6 cm = ConfusionMatrix(y, y_pred)
      7 print(cm)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_val_predict(estimator, X, y, groups, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, method)
    775     prediction_blocks = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_predict)(
    776         clone(estimator), X, y, train, test, verbose, fit_params, method)
--> 777         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    778 
    779     # Concatenate the predictions

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    915             # remaining jobs.
    916             self._iterating = False
--> 917             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    918                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
    919 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    757                 return False
    758             else:
--> 759                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    760                 return True
    761 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    714         with self._lock:
    715             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 716             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    717             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    718             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    180     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    181         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 182         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    183         if callback:
    184             callback(result)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    547         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    548         # arguments in memory
--> 549         self.results = batch()
    550 
    551     def get(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_predict(estimator, X, y, train, test, verbose, fit_params, method)
    848         estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    849     else:
--> 850         estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    851     func = getattr(estimator, method)
    852     predictions = func(X_test)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    799             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    800             check_input=check_input,
--> 801             X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
    802         return self
    803 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    114         random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)
    115         if check_input:
--> 116             X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
    117             y = check_array(y, ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    118             if issparse(X):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    525             try:
    526                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 527                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    528             except ComplexWarning:
    529                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    499 
    500     """
--> 501     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    502 
    503
```

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

I've tried resetting the Kernel but I'm confused on what the error is telling me

The code I am trying to run is this:

```
from sklearn import tree
from pandas_ml import ConfusionMatrix
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf, x, y, cv=10)
cm = ConfusionMatrix(y, y_pred)
print(cm)
cm.print_stats()
```

It should be producing the stats when ran correctly

Comment: I don't really know anything, but I guess `x` or `y` contains a timestamp rather than a string or number.

Comment: @PeterWood both of the X and Y are not numerical is that why I'm pulling the error?

Comment: As I say, I don't know anything.

Comment: do some basic debugging - print x, y, type(x), type(y), if neccessary loop thourgh x, y. Check what you believe, leverage what you know and assume nothing